# True or False Indicator when matching two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-scripts

I need some assistance, I need to pull data from my DB, now I have a FD_Documents table and FD_Revision tables.

I need to match the GUID from both tables and also need to be a revision greater than 2, once the match has been made it must add a new column within the result, QC'ed "1" for matching criteria or a "0" for not matching criteria.

I wrote the below but it does not give me result.

```
select Case when EXISTS (
       SELECT FD_Documents.GUID,
      FD_Documents.FD_C231FD9A as [Store],
      FD_Documents.FD_97CDB35A as [Store 2],
      FD_Documents.FD_8B9BD5C6 as [Transaction Date],
      FD_Documents.FD_84A4EF1A as [Account Number],
      FD_Documents.FD_1A3D602F as [Name],
      FD_Documents.FD_F8EFD019 as [Date of Birth],
      FD_Documents.FD_9DAADEC8 as [Document Type],
      FD_Documents.FD_8B43AE0B as [Year],
      FD_Documents.FD_E77BE253 as [File Name]
      FROM FD_Documents, FD_Revisions
      WHERE FD_Documents.GUID = FD_Revisions.GUID
      AND FD_Documents.Deleted = '0'
      AND FD_Revisions.Revision < '3')
      THEN CAST(1 as bit)
      ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END
```

Comment: Just use left join, with HAVING(count) clause .. and in select have that case of bit

Comment: Hi @Veljko89, thank you for your response, please could elaborate by adding your script, this will be well appreciated.

Comment: You have 'need to be a revision greater than 2' but the query is FD_Revisions.Revision < '3' - which is it?

Comment: greater than 2, apologies for the oversight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that FD_Documents.Deleted is an int or bit (not a string as in your post), and that Revision is an int (and should be greater than 2 as in your question description as opposed to your code),

```
SELECT FD_Documents.GUID,
  FD_Documents.FD_C231FD9A as [Store],
  FD_Documents.FD_97CDB35A as [Store 2],
  FD_Documents.FD_8B9BD5C6 as [Transaction Date],
  FD_Documents.FD_84A4EF1A as [Account Number],
  FD_Documents.FD_1A3D602F as [Name],
  FD_Documents.FD_F8EFD019 as [Date of Birth],
  FD_Documents.FD_9DAADEC8 as [Document Type],
  FD_Documents.FD_8B43AE0B as [Year],
  FD_Documents.FD_E77BE253 as [File Name],
  CASE ISNULL(FD_Revisions.GUID,'') WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsMatching
  FROM FD_Documents LEFT JOIN FD_Revisions
  ON FD_Documents.GUID = FD_Revisions.GUID
  AND FD_Documents.Deleted = 0
  AND FD_Revisions.Revision > 2
```

Comment: it works great, I just added a distinct close on the FD_Document, because every time there is a new revision, it records it in the revision table. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a distinct list of GUIDs in the status you require

```
select f.GUID from FD_Documents f
inner join FD_Revisions r on f.GUID = r.GUID
where f.Deleted = '0' and r.Revision>2
group by f.GUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
  SELECT FD_Documents.GUID,
      FD_Documents.FD_C231FD9A as [Store],
      FD_Documents.FD_97CDB35A as [Store 2],
      FD_Documents.FD_8B9BD5C6 as [Transaction Date],
      FD_Documents.FD_84A4EF1A as [Account Number],
      FD_Documents.FD_1A3D602F as [Name],
      FD_Documents.FD_F8EFD019 as [Date of Birth],
      FD_Documents.FD_9DAADEC8 as [Document Type],
      FD_Documents.FD_8B43AE0B as [Year],
      FD_Documents.FD_E77BE253 as [File Name],
  case when r.GUID IS NULL then 1 else 0 end [MatchCount]
  FROM FD_Documents d
        LEFT JOIN  FD_Revisions r on d.GUID = r.GUID AND FD_Revisions.Revision > '2' 
  where FD_Documents.Deleted = '0'
```

I can't say for sure, but that is idea, if you provide some testing data this query could be more specific, as this query ain't tested